# Conditional Display in a ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have the following ListView code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvOrders" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>    
        <ul id="orderList">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>           
            <% if (Mode == AdminSingle) { %>                    
                <%# Eval("Offertype")%>
            <% } %>
        <%# Eval("Something")%>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Now, my problem is that Eval("Offertype") is being evaluated in any case. But the sql query is pretty heavy for that part and I would like to only run that part of the query if I really need too. Is there a clean way around this?

I know I could do this:

```
<%# GetStatusInfo(Container.DataItem)%>
```

But then I get the display logic into my code....

Comment: As for me, a logic more complicated than just `Eval("Something")` should be evaluated in the code-behind. It makes you markup more readable. I guess your `<%# GetStatusInfo(Container.DataItem)%>` is the best option here.

Comment: The <%# Eval("Offertype")%> is just a simplified example. Actually there is some more complex display logic in there. Would you really put that into the code-behind.

Comment: yes. Isn't e.g. `<li><%# GetStatusInfo(Container.DataItem) %></li>` is more elegants than a lot of code blocks in the markup? Also if you define a method is the code-behind it could be reused in the control/page(if necessary, of course); and just imagine e.g. without it you have to copy+paste the code blocks accross the control/page.

Comment: In this case I wouldn't say using  GetStatusInfo(Container.DataItem) in the page would be putting display logic in the page, since the actual logic is inside the GetStatusInfo function, you're only calling it from the page.